# Who should I give the Magic Healing Beer to?

Tags: fiz

I've done it. I've finally completed a bottle of the magic healing beer Fiz. And now that it's done, I'm confronted with a choice. I can use it to extend the life of the already venerable convenience store magnate Edmund, who has promised me the worlds finest brewing equipment for doing so, **or**,

> I can follow through with my original plan, and save Gary Blau, at the behest of his not-sister, Zooey Blau.

I haven't been offered a reward for going with the original plan, but Z has been resourceful and provided me with goodies and helpful information before.

What's the gameplay impact of this choice?

Comment: pffft, why in the world would you want to save that asshole :P

Comment: btw, have you selected a choice yet?  I'm at the same spot now

Comment: @spartacus Nope. Figured I'd take a days break from the game.

Comment: well I went with edmund, his 3 pieces of gear provides these benefits: 100% yield, 75% brewing speed, and 40% quality

Comment: @spartacus Well then, in the interest of a complete answer, I took the other path.

Answer (score 2):

Saving Edmund nets you Brewery equipment upgrades worth **+100% Yield, +75% Brewing Speed and +40% Quality**. (H/T Spartacus - any chance you could clarify if those upgrades stack with or replace the brewery gear you may've already purchased?)

Saving Gary, by contrast, unlocks him as a new employee for the Brewery. He works for free, has Dex and Craft scores of 10, and Int and Patience of 6 and 4 respectively. He also adds **+50% Quality** of all batches brewed.

Comment: Considering that both carries over into a new game +, its entirely up to you which one you pick.  Personally I went for the equipment, I'll get the employee next time around.

Comment: and those upgrades are purchasable brewery gear that replaces your existing ones.  They just have much higher bonuses.

Comment: Strangely enough, I started a New Game +, and was given the option of hiring a *second* Gary Blau. Which, all told, seems like the best option of all.

Comment: I think I found a glitch where I can set stats to be higher than 10 by assigning multiple to a stat at level up.  I got a dude with 14 patience ATM.  Going to make a brand new game and try to get 100 crafting points lol going to have to save up a lot of levels

Answer (score 0):

Well, i saved Blau and i dont expect anything from him. I just want to save his life since Edmund is greedy and he wants to be an immortal. But, if you save Edmund it might be better since you can have better equipment and if you complete the last quest with quality 4660 beer or better you can hire Cyrus Uprum!