# Who are the secret employees and how do I get them?

Tags: fiz

[This answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/147541/3917) here hints at some employees that are not obtained the normal way.  I've beaten the game and have chosen the opposing path so 4 of my employees are still grayed out.  How do I unlock the other 3?

Comment: Hmmm... I only have two greyed out. But I'm not sure what for. I'd wager at least one is from the scientist quest I couldn't finish when my water main was broken... Did you unlock the Lumberjack?

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz no I haven't.  I skipped that marketplace on my first play through.  Now i just got the quest on my new game +

Comment: I still haven't gotten the last one, I've gotten the lumberjack, scientist, and the one in the other answer...

Comment: I've unlocked all of them but I can't for the life of me recall for sure which the last one is. I *believe* the one you're missing is Frank Cuccinello..?

Comment: @Schism probably, that name doesn't sound familiar to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The secret characters are:

#### Frank Cuccinello <sup>(I think ...)</sup>

*Please hire Frank so he gets off the couch and his wife doesn't go nuts.*

**Hiring Fee**: 200 coins
**Starting Salary**: 90 coins
**Starting Stats**: 2 / 3 / 2 / 3
**Special Ability**: +15% Quality to all Batches brewed.

How to acquire:

> Complete the event **A Beery Good Wedding**, giving many units of any beer of a medium-low quality. I had to give 362 Units of any 1273 Quality or better beer.

---

#### Eljay

*An actual lumberjack who's had trouble finding work, he's taken a liking to your beer and he's ready to put his work ethic toward helping you make it.*

**Hiring Fee**: 200 coins
**Starting Salary**: 80 coins
**Starting Stats**: 2 / 4 / 4 / 4
**Special Ability**: +10% Yield to all Batches brewed.

How to acquire:

> Complete the event **Lumber Jacked**, giving a single unit of any quality of either Red Keep IRA or Red Kastle IRA.

---

#### Prof. Zymurgis

*After successfully defending his doctoral thesis, "Modern Saccharomyces: Environments, Effects, and Deliciousness", this Prof. took a Biology professorship at State. He recently decided brewing with you might be more fun.*

**Hiring Fee**: 3000 coins
**Starting Salary**: 225 coins
**Starting Stats**: 7 / 1 / 4 / 1
**Special Ability**: 50% Chance for +100% XP.

How to acquire:

> Complete the event **Knowledge for Thirst**, giving many units of any Brown Ale of a high quality. I had to give 497 Units of any 2102 Quality or better Brown Ale.

---

### END GAME SPOILERS

> #### Gary Blau
>
> *The insufferably arrogant Blau seems to be more tolerable now that you've saved him from death. And as much as you hate to admit it, he is a fantastic brewer...*
>
>  **Hiring Fee**: Free
>  **Starting Salary**: None (Volunteer)
>  **Starting Stats**: 6 / 10 / 4 / 10
>  **Special Ability**: +50% Quality to all Batches brewed.

How to acquire:

> Complete the event **Blau for Blau**, giving your unit of Fiz to Gary.

---

There is one other secret character, but this is a super-end-game (as in end-game of NG+) spoiler. He will not appear as locked in the hiring menu.

### SUPER END GAME SPOILERS

> #### Cyrus Uprum
>
> *The brewing legend was so impressed with your beer in the last Career that he decided he'd rather work for you than retire.*
>  **Replaces your character**.
>  **Starts at Level MAX**.
>  **Cannot be fired**.
>
>  **Hiring Fee**: N/A
>  **Starting Salary**: None
>  **Starting Stats**: 10 / 10 / 10 / 10
>  **Special Ability**: +25% Quality and no Quality Cap to all Batches brewed.

How to acquire:

> Complete the event **All Grown Uprum** with an extremely high quality beer. The normal quality requirement is the boiling point of his namesake. We can deduce that he means the boiling point of Cu (copper), in Celsius which is 2562. If you double this and reach quality 5125 or better, however, this will trigger a cutscene after the credits, and the next NG+ you start will replace your character with Cyrus.

Comment: fwiw the quantity/quality requirements for events seems to be tied to your brewing ability.  I've had events requiring over 1600 units of 10000 quality beer, which is just silly.